# Getting Invalid Code Signing Entitlements after add note permission (iOS 13)

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I need to add com.apple.developer.contacts.notes and changed to manual signing because of that on iOS 13 (I got Apple permission). I can archive a version, but when I try to send it to App Store I got:

**ERROR ITMS-90045: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, key 'com.apple.application-identifier' in 'Payload/AppNAME.app/AppName' is not supported."**

Maybe the configuration for the addicional Entitlements is wrong? https://paste.pics/93699e6db73a353932fd282226503d42

My entitlements file is just:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>com.apple.developer.contacts.notes</key>
  <true/>
  <key>aps-environment</key>
  <string>production</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got a response from Apple. It was a mistake from Apple side. They removed **com.apple.application-identifier** and now it's working!

Answer (score 2):

This issue is caused by an incorrectly generated provisioning profile on Apple's side. The issue should be resolved now. You'll want to update your provisioning profile, then re-sign and re-submit your app to App Store Connect.

Answer (score -1):

As quoted on [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_contacts_notes).

> Before you can submit an app with this entitlement to the App Store,
>   you must first get permission to use the entitlement. Request
>   permission at
>   https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/contact-note-field.

Comment: I got Apple permission